# What is the actual HTTP request performed by a Facebook "Like"?

Tags: facebook, http, request, facebook-like

I know that the plugin URL isn't actually performing the Like request. There's got to be a POST or PUT request around somewhere (in the Open Graph API?) that updates the Like counter of the thing you're trying to like.

This is not for an auto-like bot or anything of that nature. Just curious if anybody knows how to make the request that actually changes stuff through HTTP alone.

Answer (score 3):

Download Fiddler and see what is actually being sent: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: I used HTTPScoop since I'm on a Mac, and I can see a bunch of stuff, but I can't find the specific HTTP request that actually writes the Like anywhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The request is:
http://www.facebook.com/ajax/ufi/modify.php?__a=1

It sends the following json:

```
{"src":10,"sty":263,"actrs":"1257436255","object_id":"491731165218","pub_time":1288891801,"fbid":126533004070932,"qid":"5535788235556603588","s_obj":5,"s_edge":1,"s_prnt":28,"pos":1,"filter":"h"}
```

Comment: Cool. Does anybody know what those key/value pairs are asking for?